# How can I change the code for the julian to gregorian and back?

Tags: c++, algorithm, gregorian-calendar, julian-date

I have these two functions and I can't get the right result for conversion from julian to gregorian calendar. The problem is that if a year is divisible by 4000 it's giving me an incorrect result as it is supposed to be a leap year but according to the requirements it's not. So I tried to add the condition but it's not working 100%.Thanks.

```
 int gregorian_to_julian(int year, int month, int day)const {
    int result=0;
    int cnt=0;//**added by me 
    if(year>=4000)//**added by me 
        cnt=year/4000;//**added by me 
    int a = (14 - month) / 12;
    int m = month + 12 * a -3;
    int y = year + 4800 -a;

    result = day + ((153 * m + 2) /5) + (365 * y) + (y/4) - (y/100) + (y/400) - 32045;
    result-=cnt;
    return result;
}

int julian_to_gregorian(int sequence, int &year, int &month, int &day)const {
    int result = 1;
    int cnt=0;
    int a = sequence + 32044;
    int b = (4 * a +3) / 146097;
    int c = a - (146097 * b) / 4;
    int d = (4 * c +3) / 1461;
    int e = c - (1461 * d) /4;
    int m = (5*e +2) / 153;

    day   =  e - ((153 *m +2) /5) +1;
    month =  m + 3 -12 * (m/10);
    year  =  100 *b + d - 4800 + (m/10);
    if(year>=4000)//**added by me
        cnt=year/4000;//**added by me
    day+=cnt;//**added by me
    return result;
}
```

Comment: An year is a leap year if it is divisible by 4.

Comment: The rule is divisible by 400, not 4000.  For example 2000 was a leap year because it is divisible by 400.

Comment: The problem I am having is that any year divisible by 4000 is not a leap year, so according to the formula it's giving me the wrong result. I agree with @KenWhite, if a year is divisible by 4 and also by 100 is not a leap year.

Comment: @btilly I know but that's what I have to do because normally the code works but because of anything not being divisible by 4000 is not a leap year, I cannot get the right result.

Comment: The year 2000 was a leap year indeed, and I searched quite a lot too. Take a look at this: [Wiki:Leap Year Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm)

Comment: _if a year is divisible by 4 and also by 100 is not a leap year._ This is quite opposite of what the internet sources say, here's another: [Microsoft: An year evenly divisible by 400 is a leap year](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/214019/method-to-determine-whether-a-year-is-a-leap-year) @btilly is fully right

Answer (score 0):

The rule is like this:

```
_leap=false;
if (year%  4==0) _leap=true;
if (year%100==0) _leap=false;
if (year%400==0) _leap=true;
// here _leap holds true if it is a leap year
```